# Laravel routing resource error

Tags: laravel

i'm using laravel 5.0

I have 2 routing :

```
Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');

Route::resource('admin/user','UserController');
```

If I browse to http://localhost:8000/admin/user

It works fine

but if I using this :

```
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');

Route::resource('admin/user','UserController');
```

The page at http://localhost:8000/admin/user will be blank!

Why? and how to fix it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Follow this order:

```
Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');

Route::resource('admin/user','UserController');

Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```

It's just the problem with the priority of the routes.

The route, `Route::get('admin/{id}', 'AdminController@show')` will take precedence over the `Route::get('admin/user', 'UsersController@show');`